# Can't create new Laravel project - unzip -qq exceeded timeout of 300

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I set up an Laravel/Homestead installation on my system (debian 9), then I wanted to create a new laravel project with

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test
```

After quite some time I get this error:

```
 The process "unzip -qq  '/home/vagrant/code/testproject/vendor/doctrine/inflector/9a39005b7c62ae74f7480316c610f0ae' -d '/home/vagrant/code/testproject/vendor/composer/9c606325'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this problem ?

I also tried

```
laravel new test
```

But I get the same error.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same problem. I updated the composer but it didn't work. Any idea ?